# How do I debug accross an FFI call in NodeJS, using VSCode?

Tags: c++, node.js, visual-studio-code, ffi

I have a NodeJS program that calls a C++ library across an FFI interface:

```
var ffi = require('ffi-napi')

var libm = ffi.Library('myLibrary.dll', {
    'test': [ 'int', [ 'int', 'int' ] ]
})

libm.test(1, 2)
```

```
extern "C" __declspec( dllexport ) int test(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

How do I setup VSCode such that I can debug both sides of the interface at the same time? Ideally I should be able to

- set a breakpoint in `libm.test(1, 2)`
- set a breakpoint in `return a + b;`
- click F5 to start debugging

And have everything just work. Installing additional extensions is ok.